# How to ignore a missing file in the imports?

Tags: nix

i have this in my nix config:

```
imports = [
    # Include the results of the hardware scan.
    ./hardware-configuration.nix
    /home/dev/user.nix
];
```

When i do now nixos-install, it tells me that user.nix doesnt exist (which is true, since the file is supplied much later).

Is there a way to only import that file when it exists or ignore that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `builtins.fileExists` function.

```
imports = [
  ./hardware-configuration.nix
] ++ lib.optional (builtins.fileExists /home/dev/user.nix) [ /home/dev/user.nix ];
```

This uses `lib.optional` to conditionally include the `/home/dev/user.nix` file in the imports list if it exists. If the file doesn't exist, `lib.optional` returns an empty list, so nothing is added to imports.

Comment: this worked :) error on my side